# Nativescript RadDataForm - propertyValidate does not fire for AutoCompleteInline

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to load autocomplete suggestions dynamically for a `AutoCompleteInline` field but the `propertyValidate` and `propertyCommitted` events do not fire for this particular field. Here's what I have:

```
    <df:RadDataForm id="orderForm" source="{{ formData }}" validationMode="Immediate" propertyValidate="dfPropertyValidate" propertyCommitted="dfPropertyCommitted">
      <df:RadDataForm.properties>
        <df:EntityProperty name="name" displayName="Name" autoCompleteDisplayMode="Plain" valuesProvider="{{ distributorNames }}" required="true" hintText="Search by Distributor/Firm Name">
          <df:EntityProperty.editor>
            <df:PropertyEditor type="AutoCompleteInline" />
          </df:EntityProperty.editor>
        </df:EntityProperty>

        <df:EntityProperty name="email" displayName="Email">
          <df:EntityProperty.editor>
            <df:PropertyEditor type="Email" />
          </df:EntityProperty.editor>
        </df:EntityProperty>
      </df:RadDataForm.properties>
    </df:RadDataForm>
```

JS

```
exports.dfPropertyValidate = function(args){
    console.log('Validate: '+args.propertyName);
}

exports.dfPropertyCommitted = function(args){
    console.log('Commit: '+args.propertyName);
}
```

The events fire just fine for the email field. And if I change the type on the first field to Text or something else, then it starts firing events as well. Only `AutoCompleteInline` somehow blocks the event.

I'm trying to load from a list of users and preloading the entire list - which could be thousands - doesn't seem practical.

**Update:**
`propertyValidate` and `propertyCommitted` both fire when an item is selected from the list. This however doesn't work for me. I need to get events while the user is typing. Are there no `propertyChange` events in RadDataForm?

Comment: Did you try `propertyEdited`?

Comment: No that didn't work. I'm not getting anything